# How to decide within #each that the element is the last?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have a simple code like this:

```
{{#each records}} {{{this}}}, {{/each}}
```

I would like to produce an output like A, B, C, D - no comma after the last element (currently, there is one indeed). So I would need to determine within the cycle when an element is the last one, or something like that. I was thinking about a helper function but as the function would not know what element is being iterated, I cannot see how that would work.

Comment: just a suggestion highly recommend this templating engine over other js templating engines as its feature rich compared to most commonly used template engines https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather should process the list outside of the render and just display the result:

```js
const list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.list = new ReactiveVar()
  this.list.set(list.join(','))
})

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  list () {
    return Template.instance().list.get()
  }
})
```

```html
{{list}}
```

Which will be `A, B, C, D`

Additionally, if you use three brackets `{{{expression}}}` then you render directly to the DOM so use this with care!

Answer (score 1):

Meteor uses the Spacebars templating language. According to [the documentation](https://www.blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each), you should prefer the newer `each ... in` syntax instead of the older `each` syntax.

Both support the special `@index` variable that you can use to easily identify the first element in the sequence. Knowing the first element, you can add a comma before every output except for the first iteration:

```
{{#each record in records}}{{#unless @index}} ,{{/unless}}{{record}}{{/each}}
```

The supported `unless` block works the same as an `if` block just with an inverted condition check.

Notice that I use double braces instead of triple-places to support escaping of special characters and prevent html injection attacks.